# Accessing Google Cloud Storage from Grails Application

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

from grails application I would like to create a blob in bucket. 
I already created bucket in google cloud, created **service account** and gave owner access to the bucket to the same **service account**. Later created service account key **project-id-c4b144.json** and it holds all the credentials.

```
StorageOptions storageOptions = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                            .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials
                            .fromStream(new FileInputStream("/home/etibar/Downloads/project-id-c4b144.json"))) // setting credentials
                            .setProjectId("project-id") //setting project id, in reality it is different
                            .build()
                    Storage storage=storageOptions.getService()
                    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("dispatching-photos", "blob_name")
                    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build()
                    Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

When I run this code, I get a json error message back.

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket dispatching-photos.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket dispatching-photos."
}
```

| Grails Version: 3.2.10
| Groovy Version: 2.4.10
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_131

google-cloud-datastore:1.2.1

google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.1

google-cloud-storage:1.2.2

Comment: Service accounts count as unique users with their own, separate set of permissions. Does the service account associated with the credentials `project-id-c4b144.json` have permission to create objects in that bucket?

Comment: @Brandon Yarbrough, yes I took client email from json file and added it as a bucket admin from "bucket permissions".

Comment: Is that the actual code you ran? It doesn't look syntactically valid (missing semicolon on a couple lines) and it looks like it's in an intermediate state of editing (the storage.get() call seems not to be needed). Also, I suspect your project ID isn't actually "project-id" - were you just doing that to hide your real project ID in the posting or was that the value you used in the code?

Comment: @Mike Schwartz, I am developing in groovy and it runs java codes as well. So in groovy, you don't need to use semicolons. Actually, the code is similar and it doesn't have storage.get() . I updated the code. Thanks for pointing out. Yes, real project id is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the service account that json file corresponds to -- I'm betting either:

A) the bucket you're trying to access is owned by a different project than the one where you have that account set as a storage admin

or B) you're setting permissions for a different service account than what that json file corresponds to

Comment: Thanks. Yes, even if the bucket was accessible by two different projects, it gave an accessing problem.  So in my case, the same bucket("dispatching-photos") was accessible by two projects: project1 and project2, the service account is created corresponding to project2. So when I created another bucket under project2 and which is not accessible by project1, creating blob in a new bucket worked. So we will investigate the issue further. I already gave thump up to your response, however, at the moment I am not sure what was the problem exactly. Once I am sure, I will keep the post updated.

Comment: The cause is probably that the service account you're using to create the objects only has storage admin permission on project2.  If you want that service account to be able to access buckets in project1, you'll also have to add that account as a project member of project1 and give it storage admin permissions.